# Parsing log file with multi-line entries

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm working on parsing a reasonable sized log file (up to 50Mb, at which point it wraps) from a third-party application in order to detect KEY_STRINGs which happened within a specified time frame. A typical entry in this log file may look like this

```
DEBUG 2013-10-11@14:23:49 [PID] - Product.Version.Module
(Param 1=blahblah Param2=blahblah Param3 =blahblah
Method=funtionname)
String that we usually don't care about but may be KEY_STRING
```

Entries are separated by a blank line (\r\n at the end of the entry then \r\n before the next entry starts)

This is for a Windows specific implementation so doesn't need to be portable, and can be C/C++/Win32

Reading this line by line would be time consuming but has the benefit of being able to parse the timestamp and check if the entry is within the given timeframe before checking if the any of the KEY_STRINGs are present in the entry. If I read the file by chunks I may find a KEY_STRING but the chunk doesn't have the earlier timestamp, or the chunk border may even be in the middle of the KEY_STRING. Reading the whole file into memory and parsing it isn't an option as the application this is to be a part of currently has a relatively small footprint, so can't justify increasing this by ~10x just for parsing a file (even temporarily). Is there a way I can read the file by delimited chunks (specifically "\r\n\r\n")? Or is there another/better method I've not thought of?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use memory-mapped files. I've personally never used them for anything but toy applications, but know some of the theory behind it.

Essentially they provide a way of accessing the contents of files as if they're memory, I believe acting in a similar way to virtual memory, so required parts will be paged-in as required, and paged-out *at some point* (you should read the documentation to work out the rules behind this).

In pseudocode (because we all like pseudocode), you would do something along these lines:

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile(...);
HANDLE file_map = CreateFileMapping(file, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, ...);
LPVOID mem = MapViewOfFile(file_map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

// at this point you can use mem to access data in the mapped part of the file...
// for your code, you would perform parsing as if you'd read the file into RAM.

// when you're done, unmap and close the file:
UnmapViewOfFile(mem);
CloseHandle(file_map);
CloseHandle(file);
```

I apologise now for not giving advice most excellent, but instead [encourage further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556.aspx) - Windows provides a lot of functionality to handling your memory, and it's mostly worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you can't use the memory, perhaps you're being a little bit too "paranoid"? Premature optimization, and all that.
2. Read it line by line (since that makes it easier to separate entries) but wrap the line-reading with a buffered read, reading as much at a time as you're comfortable with, perhaps 1 MB. That minimizes disk I/O, which is often good for performance.

Comment: 1) The memory can't be used, primarily because the application detects when it uses too much memory and will restart itself. A built in mechanism to prevent any memory leaks from running wild. Using an extra 50Mb of memory would certainly trigger this.
2) By this do you mean read a chunk (such as 1Mb) into an istream, and then call getline() on that? If so, what happens if the buffer border lies between the timestamp and the string I'm looking for? Can I flush out everything from the start of the buffer up until the timestamp and then fill the buffer again from the next part of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (as would normally be the case) all the entries in the file are in order by time, you should be able to use a variant of a binary search to find the correct start and end points, then parse the data in between.

The basic idea would be to seek to the middle of the file, then read a few lines until you get to one starting with "DEBUG", then read the time-stamp. If it's earlier than the time you care about, seek forward to the 3/4<sup>ths</sup> mark. If later than the time you care about, seek back to the 1/4<sup>th</sup>. mark. Repeat the basic idea until you've found the beginning. Then do the same thing for the end time.

Once the amount by which you're seeking drops below a certain threshold (e.g., 64K) it's probably faster to seek to the beginning of the 64K-aligned block, and just keep reading forward from there than to do any more seeking.

Another possibility to consider would be whether you can do some work in the background to build an index of the file as its being modified, then use the index when you actually need a result. The index would (for example) read the time-stamp of each entry right after its written (e.g., using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to be told when the log file is modified). It would translate the textual time stamp into, for example, a time_t, then store an entry in the index giving the time_t and the file offset for that entry. This should be small enough (probably under a megabyte for a 50-megabyte log file) that it would be easy to work with it entirely in memory.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not managed to grab one of the log files that has reached the 50Mb limit to see whether the "wrapping" is actually a rolling file or if it does literally wrap and start writing at the start of the file again. I'd assume the former, if it does turn out to be a rolling file then a binary search would definitely be nice. Just need to familiarise myself more with available IO functions, as my knowledge of this area is rather limited